# Regarding playground feature in Xcode 6

Tags: swift, xcode6

Can we use Xcode 6 Play Ground feature with Objective-C Code or with the existing applications that is already developed in objective C.

Answer (score 0):

NO. It's not possible to write objective-c code in Playground. Playground accepts only Swift.